# how do i profile invoked methods in my web application

Tags: java, jsf

My application file (EAR) consists of combination of EJB and WAR. FrameWork is JSF and IDE is Netbeans 6.9.1 applition server is glassfich V2.x. I want to calculate the execution time fro each and every invoked method in my application. i have gone through so many blogs. most of them suggested to use AOP. but nobody tell me how to configure and how to use it in my application. could anybody tell me ragarding this. If you any additional details to answer this i will provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to do AOP in Java, you're probably looking for AspectJ. ( http://eclipse.org/aspectj/ )  It's complex, but will do exactly what you're asking, and there are many books on the subject.  (I recommend you read one - it truly is that complicated)

Alternatively, if your application is using Weld/CDI, you can use an alternative which is quite a bit simpler called Interceptors: http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/interceptors.html

I'd stop short of recommending you use weld to get Interceptor support, but that's probably quicker than learning AspectJ from scratch.

Comment: If you dont mind could spare some time on disussion on this topic tomorrow

Comment: It's not something that reading what I type is going to solve for you.  What you're asking for is a complex business solution that you need to research fully.  Please read the documentation of both Weld and AspectJ, at least in a cursory fashion, and determine which you will use based on the tradeoffs of each.  (If you're already using Spring, it makes AspectJ a bit easier incidentally - transactional support in Spring is accomplished via AspectJ)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of JVM profile applications around. Have a look at something like JProbe.

Comment: I have to write code for that.I shouldnt use the third party tools

Comment: I Used AspectJ for this and its working too. thanks for all to giving your valuable suggestions.